# a link with an <a> tag?

Tags: html

I need a link within an  tag as follows:

```
<span><a data-description="TITLE - See more here" class="bullet" tabindex="-1"</a></span>
```

How can I have a link on the 'see more here' part?

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to use some JavaScript magic there. Try to take a look what e.g. JQuery can do

Comment: You can put any string you want in a `data-*` attribute. What are you actually doing with the value of that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The "data-description" attribute is by definition, without any universal semantic meaning (any attribute beginning in "data-"). It might be used by some JavaScript library to add a tooltip, but the only built-in browser tooltip is the "title" attribute which your example is not using (and that does not support HTML, only text). You need to use some library like http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip